# Javascript under the hood

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, io

I'm not a javascript programmer, but I'm trying to understand what's behind asynchronous programming, and javascript implementation with callbacks seems simple enough.
I understand That Javascript has a main loop that does something like

```
while(1){
        event = EventStack.pop()
       RunCallBacks(event)
    }
```

But let's suppose I'm making some I/O call. After the I/O has succeeded who puts that event on the stack ? Is there some background thread that's always listening to the OS and that feeds the event stack ?

EDIT:

Thanks to  elclanrs conference link, I understand better what's happening.
But There are still some things missing. For example, If i were to develop the xmlhttprequest javascript api, is this the right way to do it ? (this is very simplified pseudo-code, i just want to get the big picture)

```
Global UrlStack  # a global url stack shared by all threads
Sockets = [] # list of sockets to read from
while(1){
url = UrlStack.pop() # pop the first url in the stack
socket = CreateSocket() # create socket and send request
socket.connect(url, someport)
socket.send(request)
Sockets.append(socket)
s = select(Sockets, timeout = 0)  # use the select function provided by the OS to wait for the first readable socket
if (s is not empty){
addCorrespondingCallbacksToTheCallBackQueue()
}
}
```

Then When some javascript code wants to make an async http request, i would just add the url to UrlStack. Is this the right way to do it ?

Comment: Watch this talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Answer (score 0):

Yes; there are fundamental APIs provided by the browser that support this asynchronous queueing of callbacks.

As a JavaScript developer, what we essentially do is register callbacks for certain browser events (ie if a user clicks something, if an HTTP request returns, etc). When the browser events occur, the browser checks to see if there are any registered callbacks. If so, it will add that callback to the event queue.